# flask getting a user object in a token based authentication

Tags: python, oauth, flask, stormpath

I'm trying to figure out token based auth. specifically in stormpath .

```
1. client sign up
2. client logs in, get back a token. 
3. puts the token in the header of the following requests
4. server validates the token using stormpath api, and allows the user to enter the route.
```

this token based vs session based is confusing.

In The sessions based , i would do http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/product.html#access-user-data

```
from flask.ext.stormpath import login_required, user

@app.route('/email')
@login_required
def name():
    return user.email
```

How do I seamlessly have access to the user object in every route in token based ?

Comment: you have to store token in user model and then based on that token query your db

Comment: @HassanMehmood the question was concerning stormpath